# How does cleanup functions work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debouncing

I'm currently trying to learn React and in the process I came across a concept called debouncing. This was related to `useEffect` hook. The concept of debouncing I started to understand but what I cannot understand is how the cleanup functions work. To be more specific, I cannot understand how the return function in the `useEffect` is actually executed before all the code in the hook is.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Before cleanup');

    return () => {
      console.log('Cleanup');
    };

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Cleanup function works when useEffect method is still running and there's an update in the useEffect dependency at the same time. This generally happens when you have an unresolved fetch in the useEffect method.

In that case, useEffect terminates the first process by executing return statement and begins processing the latest useEffect call.

In your code, this will not happen because the useEffect will always terminate almost immediately when its called. Try using wait(10000) and trigger the useEffect method during that waiting time.

Comment: The effect doesn't need to keep running in order for the cleanup function to run when the dependencies change. Also, the cleanup function runs when the component is unmounted too.

Comment: The code where I came across this was actually using a ```setTimeout```. In the meanwhile, I think I started to understand why the cleanup function is executed first. I just want to verify if I get it right.

At the first execution a timer is created and a cleanup function is returned. At the second call of the ```useEffect```  the cleanup function that was returned previously is now executed, it cleans what it has to, and creates another timer plus, returns another cleanup function. Is this right?